# Apache Spark: parse PT2H5M (duration ISO-8601) duration in minutes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, iso8601

In ISO 8601, durations are in the format PT5M ( 5 minutes) or PT2H5M (2 hours 5 minutes). I have a JSON file that contains values in such a format. I wanted to know if spark can extract the duration in minutes. I tried to read it as "DateType" and used the "minutes" function to get minutes, it returned me with null values.

Example json
 `{"name": "Fennel Mushrooms","cookTime":"PT30M"}`

Currently, I am reading it as a string and using the "regex_extract" function. I wanted to know a more efficient way.

https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001437-13/reference/r_iso_8601_duration_format.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark does not provide for a way to convert ISO 8601 duration into intervals. Neither does [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) in Python `datetime` library.

However, [`pd.Timdelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) can parse ISO 8601 duration to time deltas. To support of a wider category of ISO 8601 duration, we can wrap the `pd.Timdelta` in a [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd

df = spark.createDataFrame([("PT5M", ), ("PT50M", ), ("PT2H5M", ), ], ("duration", ))

@F.pandas_udf("int")
def parse_iso8601_duration(str_duration: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return str_duration.apply(lambda duration: (pd.Timedelta(duration).seconds / 60))

df.withColumn("duration_in_minutes", parse_iso8601_duration(F.col("duration"))).show()
```

### Output

```
+--------+-------------------+
|duration|duration_in_minutes|
+--------+-------------------+
|    PT5M|                  5|
|   PT50M|                 50|
|  PT2H5M|                125|
+--------+-------------------+
```